# Import column from file with additional fixed fields

Tags: import, cassandra

Can I somehow import a column or columns from a file, where I specify one or more fields held fixed for all rows?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE users(userid int PRIMARY KEY, fname text, lname text);
COPY users (userid,fname) from 'users.txt';
```

but where lname is assumed to be 'SMITH' for all the rows in users.txt?

My actual setting is more complex, where the field I want to supply for all rows is part of the PRIMARY KEY.

Possibly something of this nature:

```
COPY users (userid,fname,'smith' as lname) from 'users.txt';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't find a native solution to this in Cassandra, my solution was to perform a preparation step with Perl so the file contained all the relevant columns prior to calling `COPY`. This works fine, although I would prefer an answer that avoided this intermediate step.

e.g. adding a column with 'Smith' for every row to users.txt and calling:

```
COPY users (userid,fname,lname) from 'users.txt';
```